# Anagram algorithm to check closeness to original

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I'm trying to create an algorithm to test if an anagram (created by another algorithm from an original word) is too close to the original word or not. The context is an anagram solving game - I want the game to generate anagrams on the fly (from words I have put into the game), but want to avoid them being too easy to solve due to the randomness leaving similarities with the original word (e.g. an anagram for BATMAN being BTAMAN).

I am an amateur, so I wanted to see if my ideas were on the right track. My current plan is based on assigning 'points' to certain criteria, then adding up the points and checking if a certain threshold is reached (meaning the anagram is too similar to the original word and should be discarded).

(Note: I've tried some 3rd party code for checking the similarity of two strings, but they seem to be heavily weighted to the string length and actual characters, which will be the same in my anagram/original word pairs)

I also want to avoid gaming the anagrams too much and creating false randomness (e.g. never having an anagram with the same starting letter as the original word).

Here's my algorithm in pseudo-code (anagrams in my game range from short words to two-or-three word strings, such as a movie title):

```
Function IsAnagramTooSimilarToOriginalWord(original, anagram) as Boolean
count = 0
if (original word 1st letter) = (anagram 1st letter) then count +=1
if (original word last letter) = (anagram last letter) then count +=1
if (any 3-letter substring from original word exists in anagram) then count +2 for each occurence
if count >=5 then return True else return False
```

And so on. I can hone the specific checks depending on the results.

I'm not asking for any code...just wondering if anyone has done anything similar before and/or if I'm making any algorithm noob mistakes. Or am I overthinking it?

I create the anagrams themselves via a simple algorithm to take a random char from the string and add it to a new string until there are none left in the original. The new algorithm would be used to check the result and (if required) redo the anagram.

Comment: i would rate the first letters lining up much higher, because it can give the game away. also, if the checks you have aren't enough, maybe you could check if a substring in both words is a word in a dictionary, i.e TMA appearing in both isn't as bad as either MAN or BAT appearing in both

Comment: I think your algorithm should be good enough. If you keep in mind the number of letters in a string. And of course, if it's a 3 worded string, you might need to check the first and last letters of each words. :)

Answer (score 2):

The weight/point system should be more elaborated.

- First, you should give MUCH more weight to the first and the last letters, for if only they are on the place, and other letters are mixed, a native reader (apart from starter or small kid) often even won't notice that. Hvae you ntioecd taht?
- You should give the same weight for all letter combinations. The more frequent ones should have bigger weight. And you have to value the rigid letter combinations. For example, in English, if the combination as ch, sh, tch, ck would be broken, the word becomes much more hard to recognize. If anagram is breaking them, it is good.
- If the new frequent letter combinations appear, it is good, too.
- If the anagram substitutes letters, that often have close sounding, it is bad.
- If the anagram regroups the letters so, that a letter becomes SOUND differently, as "c" in `sic->cis`, it is good.
- If the anagram looks and sounds as a normal word ( it uses the frequent letter combinations of the language, the longer ones - the better), it is a good anagram for two reasons - harder to solve and it is NICE.
- The sum of points should be re-valuated according to the length of the word - the longer it is, the more easy it is to do a difficult diagram.

And prepare - all weight systems have to be ***heavily*** tested. I'd advice to make a testing prog that will propose anagrams for solution and compare time spent against the evaluation and evaluate the quality of the weight system as a result. Even better, if it could evaluate the principles of weighting separately.

Surely, after such testing you could find more principles. BTW, it is a good base of PhD dissertation in psychology.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. I'm currently testing, and my algorithm is close to where I need it. I've tweaked the algorithm a few times (e.g. I needed to treat shorter words a little differently because they are much easier to 'see' instantly). It's for a simple, casual game, so although I'm tempted to make the algorithm better, I think it's good enough for its purpose at this stage. It is a fascinating topic, which came from me being too lazy to manually randomise my anagrams!

Comment: @pumpkinszwan When it will be ready, could you give here the reference? I would like to try it myself :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I'm currently testing. It's so far proven good enough for my needs, but there are some great ideas in the comments above that could improve it even more. Apologies for the VB, but that's what I use. This code is pretty generic, but specifically is VB.net WinRT code

This works well so far for words of 4 characters up to about 25 characters with multiple words.

```
Public Function IsAnagramTooSimilarToOriginal(originalWord As String, anagramWord As String) As Boolean

    ' matchPoints tracks how many matches are found between the two strings        
    Dim matchPoints As Integer = 0

    ' first letters of each string match
    If originalWord.Substring(0, 1) = anagramWord.Substring(0, 1) Then
        If originalWord.Length < 7 Then matchPoints += 3 Else matchPoints += 1.5
    End If


    ' last letters of each string match
    If originalWord.Substring(originalWord.Length - 1, 1) = anagramWord.Substring(anagramWord.Length - 1, 1) Then
        If originalWord.Length < 7 Then matchPoints += 2 Else matchPoints += 1.5
    End If


    ' first two letters match (NOTE: this is in addition to the first letters matching, so the points accumulate)
    If originalWord.Substring(0, 2) = anagramWord.Substring(0, 2) Then matchPoints += 1

    ' each three character string that appears in order in both strings
    For count = 0 To (originalWord.Length - 3)
        If anagramWord.Contains(originalWord.Substring(count, 3)) Then matchPoints += 2

    Next

    ' each four character string that appears in order in both strings
    For count = 0 To (originalWord.Length - 4)
        If anagramWord.Contains(originalWord.Substring(count, 4)) Then matchPoints += 2

    Next

    Dim result As Boolean = False

    If originalWord.Length - matchPoints <= 3 Then
        ' this makes the rules more stringent for shorter words
        result = True
    Else

        If matchPoints >= 5 Then result = True

    End If

    Return result


End Function
```